# Response/Request between Javascript/Java Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I have a simple test client-server app. Client is html/javascript, server - Java Servlet

First of all I want to test request/response mechanism. Therefore I have used a simple code for cliet(jQuery):

```
$.get ("http://localhost:8081/TestProject/BasicServlet",
       function(data) {
          alert('Data:' +data);
       }
);
```

And on the server side:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) ... {
      String callBack = "TestCallback";
      res.setContentType("text/html");
      ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
      out.write(callBack.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      out.flush();
}
```

So, Servlet catches request from client, but I have a problem with response, response header looks good, with character attributes, but I don't receive the callBack data

As response in Firebug I have 3 tabs, Header, Answer, HTML. Answer and HTML are empty

**EDIT:**
I have found a Problem: it was Access-Control-Allow-Origin violation.
Thanks for help !

Comment: Your JavaScript looks invalid (is that a function call? Where are the `()`? How do you expect an object with no values for any of its keys to work?), and I've no idea what `$` is. Prototype.js? Mootools?

Comment: Check to see in firebug if "TestCallback" is in the response.

Comment: Ah, so he did. The rest of my comment still applies though.

Comment: That's was a typo in my post, because I post from another computer and my code is on the other one

Comment: Start learning how to use debuggers.

Comment: What does $.get(...)?? Check if the url must be absolute or just the servlet, i.e. "BasicServlet"

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation in here

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream

is used for sending binary data. So my guess is that `Content-Type` header is set as some MIME type which is not recognized by jQuery. I suggest you check whether the Content-Type header is still "text/html" in the response using FireBug, or use

```
PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
writer.write(callBack);
writer.flush();
```

By the way, for sending textual data using `PrintWriter` is the recommended approach.

Comment: I don't think the text/plain is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try **out.print()** instead of **out .write()** you will get the response in your ajax call.